# jQuery Event listeners not working on Heroku Production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, turbolinks

So I have a small problem that is driving me nuts.

I have a Rails 4 app that utilizes some jQuery event listeners. These are working just great on development and staging. But when I push to production they aren't getting set.

It is worth mentioning that 'staging' is a Cedar-14 app on Heroku just like 'production'.

The only difference being that RAILS_ENV = 'staging' instead of 'production'.

If I initialize the listeners using the console, they work just great. By changing the production RAILS_ENV to 'staging' the listeners work then too.

My production.rb and staging.rb are identical. Right now assets are not being uglified or anything and as far as I can see, they are being served to the client in an identical fashion.

So my question is what is getting set by the RAILS_ENV in production that is preventing any of my '$.on' listeners from getting set?

The versions

```
jQuery 1.11.1
Rails 4.1.4
Ruby 2.2.0
Turbolinks 2.3.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check the order of your gems in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

Next step, make sure minification is not causing the issue.  Add gem 'uglifier' to your gemfile, and the following to your production.rb `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:mangle => false)`

Does any jQuery code execute?  If not and uglifer did not fix the issue, reference jQuery with `jQuery(document)` instead of `$(document)`

Still broke? Enable asset compilation fallback by adding `config.assets.compile = true` to production.rb.

If adding compilation fallback works, there may be an issue in your asset pipeline.  I don't use Heroku much, but make sure that all assets are wiped on the environment `rake assets:clobber` and also that your asset compilation is being executed on deploy `rake asset:precompile`

If still broken, please post the file with your listeners.